# Sun CC not linking to or compiling in fstream template in Shared Object

Tags: c++, stl, fstream, dlopen, suncc

I have an issue with Sun CC (6.2 mainly, but also seems to happen with 12.1) where by I cannot seem to either compile in or link to the fstream template in a Shared Object.

I've pulled this out of the legacy system I am working and reproduced it here in this example.

The C / C++ shared object (main.c):

```
extern "C" {
int xmain()
{
    fstream logstr("/tmp/log.txt", ios_base::out | ios_base::app);
    if(logstr.is_open())
    {
        logstr<<"Helloworld"<<endl;
        logstr.close();
    }
    printf("Hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
}
```

And a C main program (main2.c) :

```
int main()
{
    void *fd;
    xman *xx;

    printf("Loading library\n");
    fd = dlopen("libmain.so", RTLD_GLOBAL | RTLD_NOW);
    if(fd==NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed to open %s\n",dlerror());
        return -1;
    }
    printf("library loaded\n");
    xx = (xman *)dlsym(fd, "xmain");
    (*xx)();
    return 0;
}
```

Compile the library

```
CC -g  -o main.o -c main.C
CC -g -G -o libmain.so main.o -lCrun
```

Compile the C main program

```
cc -g -o main2.o -c main2.c
cc -g -o main2 main2.o -ldl
```

Running this produces the following error on SunOS 5.8:

```
./main2 | c++filt
Loading library
Failed to open ld.so.1: main2: fatal: relocation error: file ./libmain.so: symbol std::basic_fstream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::~basic_fstream(): referenced symbol not found
```

This is confirmed by an nm:

```
nm libmain.so | c++filt | grep stream
[55]    |         0|       0|FUNC |GLOB |0    |UNDEF  |std::basic_fstream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::~basic_fstream()
[65]    |         0|       0|FUNC |GLOB |0    |UNDEF  |std::basic_fstream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::basic_fstream(const char*,int,long)
[64]    |         0|       0|FUNC |GLOB |0    |UNDEF  |void std::basic_fstream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::close()
[53]    |         0|       0|FUNC |GLOB |0    |UNDEF  |bool std::basic_fstream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::is_open()
```

Compiler version I am using:

```
CC -V
CC: Sun WorkShop 6 update 2 C++ 5.3 Patch 111685-11 2002/10/31
```

Should I be trying to convince Sun CC to compile fstream into my library? Or is there a library which I can link against? I can't change to using stlport4 (http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/cmp_stlport_libCstd.html) as it's not available on Sun CC 6.2 (or 5.3... what's with the version numbering?).

This seems to work fine when compiling in Linux and linking against libstdc++. I'm guessing that fstream is compiled into libstdc++? (nm seems to confirm this).

Comment: What happens when you compile a standalone C++ program? Where the fstream destructor is — in the executable, in libCrun, somewhere else?